# wondering about Follow-up email after a campus interview

Tags: job-search, interview, academic-life

I had a campus visit that I thought it went very well at the beginning of Feb and I was informed that there was another candidate a week later. So it has been three weeks after they saw the final candidate.I emailed the search chair two days ago to get an update after three weeks passed. Unfortunately, I haven’t heard from her yet.You might guess I feel like I was left in the dark and this makes me a little cranky. What might be happening? Do you have any suggestion about this apart from just waiting or maybe just accepting that I didn’t get the offer?

Answer (score 0):

Who can say? Maybe they are just busy. But it is also possible that there was someone who got the first offer and they are waiting to hear if it is accepted. Sorry if that increases your anxiety, but you need to be patient.

You will hear at some point, whether it is good news or bad.